# API for Visual Studio Code

Tags: api, visual-studio-code

I want to send commands to running `VSCode`, for example `Open New File`, `Toggle Side Bar` and etc.

So it will be like remote control.

Does `VSCode` have some api to send command to?

Mouse/keyboard general control apps are not suited for me.

I want to create plugin to send commands to `VSCode` remotely.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like rmate feature in TextMate, you can use [this extension](https://github.com/rafaelmaiolla/remote-vscode). You can create ssh tunnel and edit files from ssh. Available for Ruby, Bash, Perl, Python, Nim, C, Node.js and Go (Just like rmate).

Comment: No, its not a remote editing. It is remote control, the app should be available to push "buttons" from another program. Kinda remote desktop.